# Microsoft Graph API - How to get list of active users within the last activity date

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

How to get the list of active users within the last activity date.

This is what I have tried:

```
             var department_Users_Active = await graphClient.Users.Request()
            .Filter($@"department eq '{department}'")
            .Select("displayName,signInActivity") // Users that are active
            .GetAsync();
```

I have tried this where a department is passed in but how do I get the activity of a user within the last 30 days of the user being active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very similar to get a list of inactive users. Only change relation operator from `le` to `ge`.

```
var activeDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(30)).ToString("u").Replace(" ","T");
var inactiveUsers = await graphClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Select("displayName,signInActivity")
                    .Filter($"signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime ge {activeDate}")
                    .GetAsync();
```